# Mulitple color in geom_text ggplot2 figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I would need help in order to color specific part of geom_text label within a ggplot2 figure.

Here is the code I use to produce the example :

```
library(ggrepel)
set.seed(42)

dat <- subset(mtcars, wt > 2.75 & wt < 3.45)
dat$car <- rownames(dat)

dat$colored_text <- "/A"
dat$car2 <- paste0(dat$colored_text,'-',dat$car)


p <- ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car2)) +
  geom_point(color = "red")

p1 <- p + geom_text() + labs(title = "geom_text()")
```

Here is the result of **p1** :

[image]

And I would like to color each **/** in green and each Letters **A** in blue and get something like :

[image]

DOes someone have an idea to do that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be the `ggtext` package which offers increased text rendering possibilities compared to `geom_text` and which allows to style text via markdown and or HTML/CSS like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

set.seed(42)

dat <- subset(mtcars, wt > 2.75 & wt < 3.45)
dat$car <- rownames(dat)

dat$colored_text <- "<span style='color: green'>/</span><span style='color: blue'>A</span>"
dat$car2 <- paste0(dat$colored_text,'-',dat$car)

ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car2)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") + 
  geom_richtext(fill = NA, label.colour = NA) + 
  labs(title = "geom_richtext()")
```

[image]

**EDIT** Adapting [the approach suggested by the author of ggrepel](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/145#issuecomment-557224975) to your case you could get your desired result with `ggrepel` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

dat <- subset(mtcars, wt > 2.75 & wt < 3.45)
dat$car <- rownames(dat)

phantom <- function(x) {
  paste0('phantom("', x, '")')
}

quotes <- function(x) {
  paste0('"', x, '"')
}
dat$label_green <- paste(quotes("/"), phantom('A'), quotes("-"), phantom(dat$car), sep = " * ")
dat$label_blue <- paste(phantom('/'), quotes("A"), quotes("-"), phantom(dat$car), sep = " * ")
dat$label_black <- paste(phantom('/'), phantom('A'), quotes("-"), quotes(dat$car), sep = " * ")

ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = label_green), color = "green", parse = TRUE, seed = 1) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = label_blue), color = "blue", parse = TRUE, seed = 1) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = label_black), color = "black", parse = TRUE, seed = 1) +
  labs(title = "Multi-color geom_repel_text()")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that ! I had another question : can we also add ```linebreak```by adding ```\n``` within the label text ? I tried by the line does not break for instance if I want a /n just after the ```/A```

Comment: For sure. But you have to use the html tag `<br>` instead of `\n`.

Comment: and there is no way to use that en ```geom_text_repel``` function in order to not get overlaping text elements ?

Comment: Unfortunately no as of the moment. Maybe in one of the next releases. However, see https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/145#issuecomment-557224975 for an approach to get multi-color text with ggrepel.

Comment: Yes I saw that one but i cannot manage to reproduce my example with his code

Comment: I just made an edit. A bit fiddling as I'm not that familiar with plotmath. But it works.

Comment: ... but note: TBMK it would not be easy to add linebreaks as these are not possible with math notation.

Comment: Alright thank you for that :)