# How to use geom_richtext and geom_repel_text together

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, ggrepel

My client has given me text data with HTML tags `<b>` and `</b>`. I am producing a pdf report with RMarkdown. I converted the HTML to markdown like this:

```
mutate(plot_group=as.factor(plot_group),
    ## this part inserted to replace HTML with markdown
    text.tmp = str_replace(`Item Text`, "<b>", "**"),
    text.final = str_replace(text.tmp, "</b>", "**"))
```

Then I print the result with `geom_richtext()`:

```
ggplot(items.to.plot, aes(x=plot_group, y=measure, label=wrap_strings(text.final, 16), color=as.factor(extra))) +
            geom_point() +
            geom_richtext(fill = NA, label.color = NA, hjust=-.3, size=6) +
            geom_text_repel(size=2)
```

But when I do that I get this error message:

```
Error in `geom_richtext()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
i Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error:
! gridtext has encountered a tag that isn't supported yet: <ol>
Only a very limited number of tags are currently supported.
```

I guess the problem occurs somewhere internal to `geom_text_repel()` or something, but nothing that's easy for me to fix.
I found another post on stackoverflow [that does the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987612/mulitple-color-in-geom-text-ggplot2-figure/69990877#69990877) using `phantom()` but it seems `phantom()` been removed from CRAN.

Can anyone suggest another solution?

Comment: Your error message suggests that your problem is due to the html containing `<ol>` tags, which `ggtext` cannot handle, rather than there being a problem with the interface between `ggrepel` and `geom_richtext`. Perhaps replace `<ol>` and `</ol>` with a newline character using e.g. `str_replace(text.final, "<ol>|</ol>", "\n")`

Comment: Whoa. I read your comment and kicked myself. That's the obvious thing! However, I checked my whole data set and couldn't find `<ol>` anywhere, but I'm still getting the error message from `geom_richtext`.

Comment: I also tried doing what @Allan Cameron suggested, thinking some `<ol>` escaped my notice but it didn't help.